# helm repo add exit code

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

Confused by `helm repo add` behavior

```sh
➜ helm repo add eks https://aws.github.io/eks-charts            
"eks" already exists with the same configuration, skipping

➜ echo $?
0

➜ helm repo add karpenter https://charts.karpenter.sh            
Error: repository name (karpenter) already exists, please specify a different name

✗  echo $?
1
```

so in one case this is just stdout message and error = 0, and in the latter it's stderr and error exit code = 1

I thought the behavior should be consistent, but it seems it depends on something else?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
helm repo list
```

I would imagine the return code is different since when you're trying to add eks there is already a helm config with the name `eks` that points to the same repo that you provided. So even though it cant add it (since its already there) its still considered success since the config for `eks` is the same as the parameter that you provided.

Whereas `karpenter` is likely a key that exists in your helm config but it points to a different repo than the parameter that you provided. So it cant add it and that's considered an error